# In recognition of your invaluable help

Tags: meaning

This is not a question. It's a love message from across the ocean. I know this breaks the site rules and probably will be removed, but it's important for me that you know how much I like you. I can't resist this overwhelming desire to get it out. It's important that Andrew, J.R., Stoneyb, Colleen, Sovereignsun, Mick, Weather vane, Fumblefingers and all the other great members here know that a rural woman from Egypt has been proudly including your names in my conversations with my friends. For a long time, I have browsed this site using different accounts and sometimes as a guest. I have learnt a lot, and the best I have learnt is the virtue of helping others without expecting anything in return. English has helped me see the goodness in you, the other. I wish my people, all of them, were able to see you the way I do.

Comment: I am gratified and humbled by this compliment, Sara. --and I must tell you that I, and I think everyone else here, gets as much out of it as we put into it. It is an honor to me to be of service to you and to Great Mother English!

Comment: I must admit, I didn't expect my name to be included, but you are very welcome.